# ng-click pulls and binds to scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

If in one page I have:

```
        <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
            <a ng-click="transId()" ng-href="{{ ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard ? '#/claimEnter' : '#/claimSub' }}">
                <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/submiticon.svg" >
                <p>Submit a Claim for Reimbursement</p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

And this ng-click has a function to pull a string from an API like:

```
     var _getTransId = function () {

    return $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/common/trans/claim').then(function (results) {
        return results;
    });

    $scope.transId = results;

};
```

But the original page and the page the anchor points to have their own respective controllers. Which controller is best to contain this method and hold that scope to be accessed in the landing page? I cannot get this to work anywhere and the item returned is just a string unique to the logged in user.

Comment: I love how it was down voted because of spaces in the code! This code runs and is here to get my point across....

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to your $scope.

```
var _getTransId = function () {

    return $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/common/trans/claim').then(function (results) {
        // Try setting the results.data to your scope.
        $scope.transId = results.data;
        // return results;
    });
};
```